# How can I do <form method="get"> in ASP.Net for a search form?

Tags: asp.net, forms, methods, get

I have a search form in an app I'm currently developing, and I would like for it to be the equivalent of `method="GET"`.

Thus, when clicking the search button, the user goes to `search.aspx?q=the+query+he+entered`

The reason I want this is simply bookmarkable URLs, plus it feels cleaner to do it this way.

I also don't want the viewstate hidden field value appended to the URL either.

The best I could come up with for this is:

1. Capture the server-side click event of the button and `Response.Redirect`.
2. Attach a Javascript `onclick` handler to the button that fires a `window.location.replace`.

Both feel quirky and sub-optimal...
Can you think of a better approach?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a plain old html form, not a server side form (runat=server), and you should indeed be able to make it work.

This could however be a problem if you have an out of the box visual studio master page which wraps the entire page in a server side form, because you can't nest forms.

Web forms don't have to suck, but the default implementations often do. You don't have to use web forms for everything. Sometimes plain old post/get and process request code will do just fine.

Comment: Yep, but as you state, my masterpage does wrap everything around with the main server form (since every single other page is a regular .net webform)
Thanks for the answer, though!

Comment: I have worked around that a few times by adding another placeholder outside the form, but inside the main content div. Depends on how your app is laid out, but is sometimes possible, if your nav relies on being inside the form, then probby not possible.

Comment: FYI - The "wrapper" form is only created if you do not create your own form elements. I have master pages with HTML and server-side forms in master pages all over the place :)

Comment: I would say "use a HTML form" as well though, so +1 for that part of the answer :)

Comment: I wish someone had told the people building the project I've just come on to, not to leave in the default form wrapping the masterpage.. horrendous.

Answer (score 7):

I worked on a web site that had to post to a 3rd party site to do the search on the client's web site. I ended up doing a simple Response.Redirect and passed in the search parameters through the query string like so:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string SearchQueryStringParameters = @"?SearchParameters=";
    string SearchURL = "Search.aspx" + SearchQueryStringParameters;

    Response.Redirect(SearchURL);
}
```

And on your Search.aspx page in your pageload...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["SearchParameters"]))
    {
        // prefill your search textbox
        this.txtSearch.Text = Request.QueryString["SearchParameters"];

        // run your code that does a search and fill your repeater/datagrid/whatever here
    }
    else
    {
        // do nothing but show the search page
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

This function permits to submit a page using the GET method.

To submit a page using the get method you need to:

1. add this code  **Form.Method="get";**  in the Page_Load method
2. Use this code **< asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnGenerate" />** as a submit button
3. add  **rel="do-not-submit"** attribute to all form elements that you don't want to include in your query string
4. change the codebehind logic of your page using **Request.QueryString**
5. disable the page viewstate with **EnableViewState="false"** (unless it's used for other purposes)

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ enableSubmitFormByGet(); });

function enableSubmitFormByGet(){
   if($("form").attr("method") == "get"){
        $("form").submit(function() {
            $("[name^=" + "ctl00" + "]").each(function(i){
            var myName = $(this).attr("name");
            var newName = "p" + (i-1);
            $(this).attr("name", newName);
        });
     var qs =$(this).find("input[rel!='do-not-submit'],textarea[rel!='do-not-submit'],select[rel!='do-not-submit'],hidden[rel!='do-not-submit']").not("#__VIEWSTATE,#__EVENTVALIDATION,#__EVENTTARGET,#__EVENTARGUMENT").serialize();
     window.document.location.href = "?" + qs;
     return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do (b) since (a) would require two round trips for a single query.  Alternatively, you could disable viewstate on the page, remove any other hidden fields via javascript, and also use javascript to modify the form method from post to get.  I've never done this for real, but my toy page using the included sample worked like a charm.  It's arguably easier than encoding the search string and doing the get via javascript.

Actually, it sounds like you would be happier with ASP.NET MVC since this is easily doable there by simply setting the form method to GET in the view.

sample code using jquery

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
     $('input[type=hidden]').remove();
     $('form').attr('method','get');
 });
```

**EDIT:** It seems like you ought to be able to do the same thing server-side, too. Maybe in OnPreRenderComplete.  Don't have access to Visual Studio right now to check.

Answer (score 0):

I have always used Response.Redirect as it "works".

I don't think there is an optimal method.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this in your .click event before the form submission:

```
    $("#__VIEWSTATE").remove();
    $("#__EVENTVALIDATION").remove();
```

Comment: It removes the viewstate and eventvalidation strings from the resultant querystring generated by the form GET method. You stick that in your form submission event or submit button click event.