# button in ASP.NET are all post method?

Tags: asp.net, http, post, get

Are all button control has to be post method? or we can set it to get method, for example, I want to see an employee details by giving `employeeId` and click submit button

Comment: Provide you question with piece of code or after summary of your valuable efforts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do <form method="get"> in ASP.Net for a search form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319413/how-can-i-do-form-method-get-in-asp-net-for-a-search-form)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between GET and POST method. They both provide url and parameters. POST method only have some advantages and some restrictions.

If your button is on form (as in classic asp.net), and there is no javascript handler for this button - only POST method can be here.

If you create jquery code (or pure javascript), that overrides default behaviour of the button, you can select what method use: POST or GET

```
<script>
$('#button').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
       url: '....',
       data: { ....},
       type: 'GET', //or 'POST'
       success: function(res) {
          //all fine
       },
       error: function() {
          //invalid url or server error
       }
   };
   return false; //to avoid default submit
});
</script>
```